# How do I add my address to a deployed contract public address using a security exploit? (coding challenge)

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets

I'm working on a coding challenge for smart contract security exploits. I need to add my address to public address (browerr) in the contract. Do I need to create another contract that inherits the original contract and calls one of the functions? Or somehow set the lock variable to true?

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT 
pragma solidity 0.8.20;
contract A {
    address public browerr;
    address private owner = address(this);
    uint internal ETH;

     event ETHUpdate(uint256 ETH);
     event ETHsent(address , uint);
     event BrowerrOperationsAddress(address _newBrowerr);
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender==owner, "Caller is not a owner");
        _;
    }
    
    function setAddress(address _browerr) external onlyOwner{
        checkContract(_browerr);
        browerr = _browerr;

        emit BrowerrOperationsAddress(_browerr);
    }
    function checkContract(address _account) internal view {
        require(_account != address(0), "Account cannot be zero address");

        uint256 size;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { size := extcodesize(_account) }
        require(size > 0, "Account code size cannot be zero");
    }
     function sendETH(address _account, uint256 _amount) external {
        _requireCallerIsBOorTroveMorSP();
        ETH = ETH.sub(_amount);
        emit ETHUpdate(ETH);
        emit ETHsent(_account, _amount);

        (bool success, ) = _account.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "failed to send Transactions");
    }

    function _requireCallerIsBOorTroveMorSP() internal view {
        require(
            msg.sender == browerr,
            " Caller is neither browerr"
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the owner variable is set to `address(this)`, contract has to call itself to satisfy the onlyOwner modifier to set the `browerr` variable. Can be achieved by:

```
contract B is A {
    function setAddress2(address _browerr) external {
        (bool success, ) = address(this).call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setAddress(address)", _browerr)
        );
        require(success);
    }
}
```

This will do the job, but would allow anyone to call `setAddress2`.